# Custom converter for character varying column - parameter in from method is null

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm having an issue related to the custom converter and String value.

Setup:

JOOQ version - 3.11.0

forcedTypes section in maven plugin:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <userType>com.test.SomeObject</userType>
    <converter>com.test.SomeObjectConverter</converter>
    <expression>some_object</expression>
    <types>.*</types>
</forcedType>
```

some_object sql definition:

```sql
some_object character varying(255) NOT NULL
```

The converter itself:

```java
public class SomeObjectConverter implements Converter<String, SomeObject> {

    @Override
    public SomeObject from(final String s) {
        return new SomeObject(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String to(final SomeObject someObject) {
        return someObject.getFieldsThatsString();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> fromType() {
        return String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<SomeObject> toType() {
        return SomeObject.class;
    }
}
```

The field in generated JOOQ record has correct type

```java
public final TableField<SomeTableRecord, SomeObject> SOME_OBJECT
```

Unfortunately when I execute the query

```java
dslContext.insertInto(SOME_TABLE)
            .set(SOME_TABLE.SOME_OBJECT, new SomeObject("string")).execute();
```

The `SomeObjectConverter` does not handle this properly because the parameter `final String s` in `from` method is null which results in unexpected behavior

EDIT: Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.SomeObject.<init>(SomeObject.java:16)
    at com.test.SomeObjectConverter.from(HierarchyIdConverter.java:10)
    at com.test.SomeObjectConverter.from(HierarchyIdConverter.java:6)
    at org.jooq.impl.ConvertedDataType.convert(ConvertedDataType.java:105)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:19800)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:19769)
    at org.jooq.impl.FieldMapsForInsert.addFields(FieldMapsForInsert.java:287)
    at org.jooq.impl.FieldMapsForInsert.set(FieldMapsForInsert.java:315)
    at org.jooq.impl.FieldMapsForInsert$2.put(FieldMapsForInsert.java:402)
    at org.jooq.impl.FieldMapsForInsert$2.put(FieldMapsForInsert.java:368)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractStoreQuery.addValue(AbstractStoreQuery.java:85)
    at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.set(InsertImpl.java:688)
    at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.set(InsertImpl.java:126)
    at com.test.Repository.insertSomeObject(Repository.java:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in jOOQ: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7742

The reason for jOOQ's call to your converter with a `null` argument is because in the case of multi-row `INSERT` statements that do not set the same column on each row, there needs to be a placeholder bind value for the missing column on each row. Example:

```java
dslContext.insertInto(SOME_TABLE)
          .set(SOME_TABLE.SOME_OBJECT, new SomeObject("string"))
          .newRecord()
          .set(SOME_TABLE.SOME_OTHER_OBJECT, "other")
          .execute();
```

In the above case, the second row would need to yield a `null` value for the `SOME_OBJECT` column for the insert statement to be syntactically correct.

Of course, in your case, this shouldn't apply. The `null` value initialisation should be implemented more lazily inside of jOOQ.

#### Workaround

Make your converter `null` safe, e.g.:

```java
public class SomeObjectConverter implements Converter<String, SomeObject> {

    @Override
    public SomeObject from(final String s) {
        return s == null ? null : new SomeObject(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String to(final SomeObject s) {
        return s == null ? null : s.getFieldsThatsString();
    }

    ...
}
```